# Certain namespaced routes being ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following routes

```
  resources :eclubs, except: [:show]
  namespace :eclubs do
    resources :leaders, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :members, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy]
  end
```

However, /eclubs/members does not routes to the index action of the Eclubs::Members controller. Instead it routes to the show action of the Eclubs controller. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is declared first, the Eclubs controller is being given precedence over the Eclubs::Members. Instead declare the Eclubs controller's routes last e.g.

```
  namespace :eclubs do
    resources :leaders, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy]
    resources :members, only: [:index, :show, :new, :create, :destroy]
  end
  resources :eclubs, except: [:show]
```